# How to automatically resize a plot on the important part, not showing the white parts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am currently trying to plot figures like this :

[image]

where i'm generating some random polytope located inside [-1,1]x[-1,1], then applying some optimization algorithms, and then plotting everything.

The problem is that because the polytopes are randomly generated, they can be very small or not centered,  and it would be therefore convenient if i could remove the blank part on the sides.

I know it's possible to do it when saving a plot with something like plt.savefig('image.png', bbox_inches='tight'), but i would like to display it directly without white spaces (it's in a jupyter notebook so it would be more convenient).

I'm using a meshgrid to plot the data, and i have a 'None' at every blank pixel. I guess it could be possible to find some algorithm which finds the smallest square enclosing my polytope but i don't really want to go this way.

Do you have any ideas on how to do it using matplotlib ?